# React Hook Conditional Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to either render nothing or render DOM elements dependent on the users variable:

```js
const Users = (props: UserProps) => {
  const [users, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, []);

  return (
    users && (
      <span>
        <div className="padding-bottom-50">
          <div className="section-heading">
            New Users
          </div>

         <Users users={users} />

       </div>
      </span>
    ) || null
  );
};
```

It's still showing `"New Users"` text even when users is null or undefined

Comment: When is `users` null or undefined? The default is an empty array, which is truth-y. If it *was* false-y, you wouldn't see "New Users".

Comment: once again you nailed it, didn't see that either ughhhh.  I'm so used to coding in Class Components

Comment: This is nothing to do with function vs. class components, the logic would be the same with `this.state.users`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Users` is an array. Therefore `users &&` will always be true.

Instead, check the length of users, like this.

```js
const Users = (props: UserProps) => {
  const [users, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //
  }, []);

  if (users.length < 1) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <span>
      <div className="padding-bottom-50">
        <div className="section-heading">New Users</div>
        <Users users={users} />
      </div>
    </span>
  );
};
```

Comment: if users becomes null/undefined for whatever reason won't this logic break

Comment: @RobertTerrell yes, this would throw an error if you attempted to access length of null/undefined. You could protect against this by modifying the condition to be `if (!users || users.length < 1)`